# htaccess redirect directories to index.html

Tags: htaccess, directory

I am working on a site where I do not have permission to access the server config and someone else keeps changing the settings. That person just changed the settings preventing users from going to `example.com/foo/` and seeing the index page.

> This Virtual Directory does not allow contents to be listed.

If you type in `example.com/foo/index.html` you can still see the file.

So I want to use `.htaccess` to redirect all URLs that end in a directory to  `directory/index.html`. How do I write that?

I started with some code that changes `.php` files to `.html` files and tried to work from that but I couldn't quite get it to work.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.php$ /$1.html [R=301,L]
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is not a `mod_rewrite` directive - take a look at the [Apache `mod_dir` documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_dir.html) - something like this should be a good start for your `.htaccess` file:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm
```